# Open Sans does not get selected

Tags: fonts

I am trying out a few fonts but I am struggling with OpenSans. If I select it a different font seems to be selected that look nothing like OpenSans and also does not look smooth at all. What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{opensans}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{Blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \Blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems to be connected to `\sfdefault`. Is OpenSans not defined as a sans serif font?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/opensans/doc/opensans.pdf), you need to add an option to your `\usepackage{opensans}` to get it actually to change the font.  So to set it as the sans font you should do this:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[defaultsans]{opensans}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}
    \Blindtext
\end{document}
```

but actually there is another option that removes the need for the `renewcommand` line:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[default]{opensans}
\begin{document}
    \Blindtext
\end{document}
```

This `default` option, sets opensans as the font for the whole document.  The whole document, that is, apart from any math environments:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[defaultsans]{opensans}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}
\section{Heading}

In particular, any associated supporting element necessitates that urgent
consideration be applied to possible bidirectional logical relationship approaches.
\[ e = mc^2 \]
Conversely, any associated supporting element recognizes other systems' importance
and the necessity for possible bidirectional logical relationship approaches.
However, a service-oriented paradigm is further compounded when taking into account
the evolution of specifications over a given time period.  
\end{document}
```

The documentation linked above explains what else you have to do to get matching maths.

[image]